# Order preserve after taking expectation "piecewisely"

Tags: calculus, probability

There are four continuous functions $\mathbb{R^+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^+}$, $g_1(x),g_2(x),g_3(x),g_4(x)$, and they satisfy $g_1(x)g_2(x)<g_3(x)g_4(x)$ for $\forall x$,

I'm wondering under what conditions about $g$ or their relationship will we have $E[g_1(x)]E[g_2(x)]<E[g_3(x)]E[g_4(x)]$ for an arbitrary probability distribution.

Comment: Although not sure about this, my intuition tells me total positivity may play a role here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One condition is when $g_1(x), g_2(x), g_3(x)$ are non-decreasing in $x$ and $g_4(x)$ is non-increasing in $x$. Then:

$$ E[g_1(X)g_2(X)] \leq E[g_1(X)g_2(X)] \leq E[g_3(X)g_4(X)] \leq E[g_3(X)]E[g_4(X)] $$

where the middle inequality uses your assumption $g_1(X)g_2(X) \leq g_3(X)g_4(X)$ for all $X$.

---

This uses the fact that if $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ are non-decreasing in $x$ then $f(X)$ and $h(X)$ have non-negative covariance. This can be proved by the fact that $(f(X)-f(Y))(g(X)-g(Y)) \geq 0$ for all $X, Y$. Taking $X, Y$ iid and taking expectations proves the result.